# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined Getting this error after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want the save the value of the input field with **handeleSubmit** for that I have given a piece of code in my form :

```
const MessageForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmit }) => (
  <section className="form-container register-model-form">
   <form className="message-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Input
      label="Write a message..."
      name="message"
      type="text"
    />
```

while implementing my code for the handleSubmit part I am getting an error: **Cannot read property 'type' of undefined**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import SubMenu from './SubMenu';
import MessageForm from './form/MessageForm';
import * as action from '../../actions/messages.actions';
import { sendNewMessage } from '../../actions/messages.actions'

class Messages extends React.PureComponent {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.sendNewMessage();
      } ;
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="page-notifications"> 
                <SubMenu/>
                <MessageForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
      sendNewMessage: () => dispatch(action.sendNewMessage()),
  });

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Messages)
```

**I want to save the value as an array, for that, I wrote my code for reducer :**

```
const messages = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_MESSAGE":
      return state.concat([{
        message: action.payload.message,
        author: action.payload.author,
        id: action.payload.id,
      }]);
    case "MESSAGE_RECEIVED":
      return state.concat([{
        message: action.payload.message,
        author: action.payload.author,
        id: action.payload.id,
      }]);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default messages;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like `action` is undefined in your reducer

Comment: I am not getting your point .. can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: if you `console.log(action)` in your reducer, you will see it is undefined so you need to figure out where that variable is being passed into the function and make sure it is defined, if you are expecting the `action` you import at the top of the page, then you may want to call the function variable something else as it will be overriding the global action